# If Vikings Settled on a Tropical Island, How Would That Affect Up The Native Ecosystem?

Tags: environment, fauna, space-colonization, ecology, vikings

An ice age has hit the already cold planet of Ryu 108. Its inhabitants, with the culture and technology of Scandinavia at the height of the viking age, are forced to feed themselves with a drastically reduced amount of arable land. As a result, many who once lived in the planet's more northerly regions are forced to leave or starve, since the south is already overflowing with climate refugees.

Now, around 23,000 of these vikings have decided to leave the planet entirely (space travel in this universe is done by rigging magic crystals to the masts of sea vessels). Eventually, these vikings stumbled upon an uninhabited tropical archipelago "Eyjagard".

**Before I discuss Eyjagard, here is what the vikings are bringing with them:**

-23,000ish settlers from all segments of society

-Their religion (Norse paganism)

-Their technology (iron weapons, longships, etc.)

-These non-native animals to Eyjagard (livestock, pets, and stowaways): dogs, cats, chickens, pigs, sheep, goats, cattle, horses, ponies, unicorns (same biology and behavior as horses, just add a horn), domesticated woolly mammoths, domesticated woolly rhinos, wargs (domesticated direwolves roughly the size of horses, behave basically like giant dogs), house mice, black rats

-These non-native food crops: barley, wheat, rye, oats, apples

**A word about natives**

The Eyjagard archipelago is completely uninhabited. Nobody has ever lived there before. However, there are peoples living on other archipelagos throughout Atlantea (Atlantea has no continents but is dotted with several archipelagos, almost all of which are tropical due to Atlantea's proximity to its sun and mountainous due to a long chain of events I don't have time to discuss here). Below are a list of peoples on Atlantea and what you need to know about them:

-Kangaroo Islanders (Kangaroo Islanders hail from Kangaroo Island, a misnomer and the planet's largest archipelago. Far to the north of Eyjagard and without much in terms of seafaring technology, these people will not be very relevant in the immediate future, though they may come into play later if the new Eyjagardians do enough exploring. Their culture and tech is an amalgamation of pre-contact Australian Aboriginal and Papuan cultures).

-Platypusians (From the archipelago of Platypusia to the north of Kangaroo Island, meaning they are REALLY far away, these people will, however, be relevant in the immediate future for one reason: advanced seafaring technology and skills. Their culture and tech resembles that of the Maori from New Zealand).

-Dolphinesians (From the archipelago of Dolphinesia between Eyjagard and Kangaroo Island, the Dolphinesians are the closest natives to Eyjagard. In fact, the Dolphinesians know of Eyjagard's existence, having embarked on numerous fishing expeditions on the northern shores but never establishing a settlement there. The Dolphinesians, like their faraway Platypusian cousins, are highly skilled seafarers and navigators, having established contact with all of Atlantea's tribes and civilizations. Their culture and tech is an amalgamation of various Polynesian, Melanesian, Micronesian, Filipino, and Indonesian cultures, with particular emphasis on Native Hawaiians and Majapahit).

By trading with the natives, the settlers can obtain these new food crops: Bananas, plantains, pineapples, betel nuts, breadfruit, taro, cassava, kava, noni, coconuts, sugarcane, and sweet potatoes

**Intro to Eyjagard**

While dozens of islands make up the Eyjagard archipelago, there are two that make up more than 95% of the archipelago's total landmass: Nordgard in the north and Sudgard directly southwest of it, separated by a narrow strait. As a result, the shape of the archipelago roughly resembles New Zealand. These islands are roughly equal in size. While both of the islands are highly mountainous, Nordgard's proximity to the equator keeps any snow-capped peaks from forming. Sudgard, on the other hand, is colder and more similar to the viking homeland of Ryu 108, with many snow-capped peaks, glaciers, volcanoes, and fjords.

**ECOSYSTEMS: NORDGARD COASTAL RAINFORESTS**

Nordgard is the northern and more tropical of the two islands, with no snow-capped peaks, despite having mountains of roughly equal altitude to the colder Sudgard. The lowlands along the coast are hot, humid, and covered in tropical rainforest, with similar vegetation to the real-world islands of Borneo or Java. Most of Eyjagard's arable land is found here. However, an interesting mix of native creatures inhabits these coastal rainforests and shallow waters just offshore:

HERBIVORES:

-Babirusa

-Cassowary

-Brokey Strait Iguana (Marine Iguana)

-Brokey Strait Finch (Galapagos Finch)

-Black Swan

-Bird of Paradise

-Misc. Tropical Fish

-Eyjagard Giant Tortoise (Galapagos Giant Tortoise)

-Gigantopithecus

-Green Sea Turtle

-Jungle Hornbill (Papuan Hornbill)

-Jungle Rhino (Sumatran Rhinoceros)

-Palm Cockatoo

-Budgerigar

-Sambar Deer

-Tree Kangaroo

-Grey Kangaroo

-Water Buffalo

-Eyjagard Iguana (Galapagos Land Iguana)

-Flying Fox (The giant fruit bat, not a literal winged fox)

-Sulphur-crested Cockatoo

OMNIVORES/SMALL CARNIVORES:

-Atlantean Penguin (Little blue penguin)

-Atlantean Pelican (Australian Pelican)

-Flightless Comorant

-Brokey Strait Penguin (Galapagos Penguin)

-Magpie (Australian Magpie)

-Goanna (Misc. mid-sized monitor lizards)

-Eyjagard Fur Seal (Galapagos Fur Seal)

-Magnificent Langskip (Magnificent Frigatebird)

-Tiger Quoll

-Duck-billed Platypus

-Misc. Snakes

TOP PREDATORS:

-Eyjagard Alligator (American Alligator)

-Saltwater Crocodile

-Megalania

-Dingo

-Giant Eagle (Philippine Eagle)

-Misc. Sharks

-Eyjagard Panther (Florida panther)

MISC. VENOM HAZARDS:

-Irukandji

-Box Jellyfish

-Sea Krait

-Stonefish

-Crown-of-thorns Starfish

-Misc. Spiders

**ECOSYSTEMS: NORDGARD HIGHLANDS**

Inland as elevations rise, temperatures drop, leading to a climate similar to that of the New Guinea Highlands. However, the humidity from the sea pooling over the mountains has allowed a vast redwood forest to grow here.

HERBIVORES:

-Wallaby

-Sambar Deer

-Mountain Elk (Red deer)

-Megaloceros

-Mountain Camel (Dromedary with the fur of a Bactrian)

-Gigantopithecus

-Flying Fox

-Black Swan

-Grey Kangaroo

OMNIVORES/SMALL CARNIVORES:

-Redwood Devil (Tasmanian Devil)

-Duck-billed Platypus

-Magpie

-Thylacine

TOP PREDATORS:

-Megalania

-Thylacoleo (a MUCH larger version over 6ft tall and 12ft long)

-Dingo

-Giant Eagle

**ECOSYSTEMS: SUDGARD**

Sudgard is much more uniform than Nordgard, being covered in coniferous forests basically throughout, with the sole exceptions of glaciers and snow-capped peaks. Fjords dot the landscape, as the mountains frequently go all the way to the coasts.

HERBIVORES:

-Southern Moose (Moose)

-Sambar Deer

-Mountain Elk

-Mountain Camel

-Megaloceros

-Gigantopithecus

-Raven

-Common Loon

-Black Swan

-Wallaby

-Grey Kangaroo

-Lemming

-Misc. Fish

OMNIVORES/SMALL CARNIVORES:

-Magpie

-Thylacine

-Duck-billed Platypus

-Atlantean Penguin

-South Eyjagard Penguin (Magellanic Penguin)

-Atlantean Pelican

-TOP PREDATORS:

-Taiga Bear (Short-faced bear Arctodus Simus)

-Dingo

-Giant Eagle

NOW, FINALLY, MY QUESTION

If this is the setup going in, how will the Eyjagardians fare in their new home after 100 years? How would their invasive species screw up these ecosystems and/or lead to the extinction of native species?  Would they domesticate any native species?

Comment: Holy wall-o-text, batman. I think everyone would appreciate a précis. I'm fairly certain there's a lot of irrelevant fluff there that can be immediately zapped.

Comment: They will decimate native vegetation to brew all kind of exotic mjød.

Comment: Also, one question please.

Comment: How large are those islands? 23,000 people and their pets on an island the size of Great Britain is one thing, same people and pets on an island the size of Corfu is quite another.

Comment: The "mostly" of the planet being "mostly tropical" is due to the inclination of the planet's axis, not its distance from its sun.  The distance from the sun allows for tropical weather; the inclination determines what fraction of the planet has similar length days and nights throughout the year.

Comment: I'm VTC as too broad for now because you have asked multiple broad questions. The affect of an invasive species is for example too broad, and you have introduced multiple species. I recommend looking at the impact of introducing hoofed animals in Australia and its impact on native fauna or the introduction of rodents in New Zealand as starting points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i read and grasp of the list, most non native Eyjagard animal wont screw up the native species, base of my observation from my own country (majority of it is livestock anyway, they are everywhere including tropical country al though some generate different trait or adaptation).

except cat which as far as i know has extinct/endangered several bird species in  [new zealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats_in_New_Zealand) or [australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats_in_Australia).

the rest especially livestock will have trouble surviving in this kind of wildlife they just become easy prey, they generally will just live around the viking village and depend on the people to ward off native predator, except woolly mammoths, domesticated woolly rhinos, and wargs for the Sudgard or colder climate,i doubt they can survive in hotter climate, although i know mammoth at least has some migration to south east asia in ice age, but i think the climate is quite different than tropical today, its not like elephant and rhino not exist in south east asia afterall so the mammoth may evolve to elephant but i doubt it can developed under 100 years.

also they probably wont thrive in Nordgard Higlands, since it has Megalania or giant komodo dragon which as far as i know prey on big animals such as pigmy elephant, so you know regions that have komodo dragon dont have elephant and rhino for some reasons.

so for Sudgard at least they may impact the foodchain, for wolly mammoth as far as i read their diet, they can eat tree leaf (i dont know what type they can eat) but if they cant eat the type in the descriptions, then this definitelly will devastatingly disturb the grass or moss in sudland to impact the herbivore there, for woolly rhino they eat variety of grass plant but i dont think it will impact much compare to feeding a big elephant, while i dont know what impact wargs can bring, but they generally seems like bigger wolf so probably it will compete with the dingo or outmatch them as top canine predator.

and another invasive species that can impact the landscape is the viking itself, to build their own village or housing and field for the animals/farming or from their general lifestyle or culture.

for domesticating Eyjagard native animal

waterbuffalo probably one of it (the rest is to wild to domesticate even for native people, maybe some for pet but even so they mostly still wild and can be agressive), since its a common domesticate bull in south east asia i doubt the viking has trouble with it since i believe its pretty much the same how to treat a bull, except you can make cage/pen in the middle of river/lake because they can swim but not a must/necessary though.

regarding can the viking thrive in this environment it depend, if there any tropical disease in this land, since the viking is not native, they wont have the immune system to fight it or have alot of struggling to develop the immune system, unless they know the native traditional herbal or medicine, or know how to treat it, or the viking is very fit, and vice versa can bring the viking disease to the native people, just like native american/australian get disease or epidemic from first contact with european explorer/colonist.